# ошибка при компеляции pyinstaller eel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, eel

Раньше при компиляции скрипта при помощь `pyinstaller` все было хорошо. Запускаю так

```
python -m eel stat1.py web --onefile --noconsole
```

Теперь получаю вот такую ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? Раньше собирал приложение на python 3.7 , сейчас 3.9 сам скрипт через консоль запускается.

```
Building executable with main script 'stat1.py' and web folder 'web'...

Running:
pyinstaller stat1.py --hidden-import bottle_websocket --add-data C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js;eel --add-data web;web --onefile --noconsole

720 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
720 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
720 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
720 INFO: wrote C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat1.spec
728 INFO: UPX is not available.
730 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\Desktop\\stat',
 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\Desktop\\stat']
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
811 INFO: checking Analysis
811 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
811 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
811 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
821 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
3796 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3796 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib'
11296 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
11467 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
11477 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
11539 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll
11570 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat1.py
11577 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'bottle_websocket'
11793 INFO: Processing module hooks...
11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11793 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
11878 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
12328 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
40832 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
40832 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
40832 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi', 'greenlet', 'setuptools']
41936 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\vadim.sharoikin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 27, in <module>
    import stat as st
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\Desktop\stat\stat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc, datetime,time,eel, jinja2
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gevent.threading import Timer
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    import socket  # pylint:disable=unused-import,useless-suppression
  File "C:\Users\vadim.sharoikin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 67, in <module>
    __all__.extend(os._get_exports_list(_socket))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'os' has no attribute '_get_exports_list' (most likely due to a circular import)
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.
```

Comment: Дайте код, тогда будет понятнее. Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module. Четко говорит, что не может импортировать модуль сайта. Может вам виднее, что за модуль и что за сайт? Покажите список импорта в файле